# How to convert double-byte UTF-16 Unicode characters to ASCII and then to decimal?

Tags: unicode, vbscript, utf-16

When I use `Hex (AscW (Mid (strBuffer, i, 1)))` in VBScript, it gives me 2 bytes at a time, and with the positions flipped, e.g. `F192`, which should be `92F1`.

Notice that `strBuffer` is a binary stream.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Windows gives you the least significant byte first because that is how Intel make their processors.

Comment: AscW has nothing to do with ASCII. Perhaps you know that already. Are you saying that strBuffer is a stream of text encoding inUTF-16BE? If so, you should go back to the step that is stuffing it into a String because that datatype is for UTF-16LE. You can [edit] your question to show that code.

Comment: I'm new to all this, and as I can see I couldn't even formulate the question accurately. I want to be able to extract all the unicode bytes from a binary stream (it encodes the size of a mp3 file.) After I convert the characters to hex, I convert the final hex to decimal, and that's the embedded art size. I've managed to do that by using Hex (AscW (Mid (strBuffer, i,1))) as an ordinary string , but I want to know how to do that properly.

Comment: Your main problem is that you are treating **binary** data as if it were **text** data. Don't do that! Do not store binary data in a string at all. Use things [like ADODB.Stream](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.vbscript/1OhVCKXHdcg) instead. But if you must use a string, at least use byte-oriented functions, like `MidB()` instead of `Mid()`, for instance. `MidB()` operates on bytes, `Mid()` operates on characters (and as you've noticed, characters are 2 bytes). There are other `B` functions available (`LenB()`, `AscB()`, `ChrB()`, etc)